# How to extract a number of bytes from within a 'bytes' list and put into a new 'bytes' list

Tags: python, list

I have a device running a modified modbus protocol. The device sends messages to the RPi3 serial port. The message is 14 bytes long that starts with a sync byte followed by 11 data bytes then two modbusCRC-16 bytes.

In order to check the validity of the message (by way of a CRC check), I can only send the 11 data bytes to the CRC check function. The problem is, I just can't figure out how to extract those 11 bytes and put them into new bytes list(??) acceptable by the CRC function.

The program is shown below and the output below it (the error shown is understood because the `newData` list has not been created - that's what I'd like some help with).

```py
import serial
from time import sleep
from modbus_crc import check_crc
    
    
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", 9600)
    
print("waiting for  message from the serial port ......\n")
rxData = ser.read()
sleep(0.03)
data_left = ser.inWaiting()
rxData += ser.read(data_left)
    
print("Message has been received\n")
print("The 'rxData' type from ser.read() is ",type(rxData), " and length is ", len(rxData))
print("'rxData - ", [hex(i) for i in rxData], "\n")
    
print("Now show only bytes 1 to 11 of rxData\n")
    
x = range(1,12,1)
for i in x:
    print((hex(rxData[i])), end=" ")
print("\n")
    
#####################
#### Missing code to make newData  with only the bytes (1 to 11 in rxData
#####################
        
print("\nThe 'newData' type is ",type(newData), " and length is ", len(newData))
print("'newData' - ", [hex(i) for i in newData], "\n")
    
print("\n")
print("check if newData CRC is OK\n")
    
if not check_crc(newData):
    print("CRC is NOT OK")
else:
    print("CRC is OK!")
```

Output after running the program:

```
waiting for  message from the serial port ......

Message has been received

The 'rxData' type from ser.read() is  <class 'bytes'>  and length is  14
'rxData -  ['0xff', '0xd', '0x77', '0x2', '0x1', '0x1', '0x12', '0x33', '0x30', '0x2e', '0x38', '0x39', '0xfd', '0x78'] 

Now show only bytes 1 to 11 of rxData

0xd 0x77 0x2 0x1 0x1 0x12 0x33 0x30 0x2e 0x38 0x39 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stevev/Projects/TKinter/20240309-operation on Bytes class.py", line 29, in <module>
    print("\nThe 'newData' type is ",type(newData), " and length is ", len(newData))
NameError: name 'newData' is not defined
```

Comment: The error message you get seems to have little to do with what you are asking. You should fix the errors first before posting your code here.

Comment: To create a list, write `newData = []`.

Comment: please provide a [mcve] with inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I'm almost certain they don't actually want a `list`.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, you need to use a slice: `new_data = rxData[1:12]`

Comment: @Lesiak - Thank you. It was exactly what I needed to do. And thanks to others for input. I'm learning about Python very gradually as I go and you help is invaluable. Cheers Steve

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you need to use a slice

```
new_data = rxData[1:12]
```

See:

- [Python Tutorial - Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)
- [How slicing in Python works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/how-slicing-in-python-works)